# How to increase size of images means its height and width of images in android gallery strip

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-studio, android-activity

I have changed the height & width of the Gallery tag in my code, but nothing has happened. Please guide me to right path.

Here is a screenshot of my gallery images

[image]

And here is my XML code

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ll_brand_color_slider_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/ll_product_view"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btnColorPrvious"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/left_e"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

    <Gallery
        android:id="@+id/brand_color"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:background="@drawable/slide_bg"
        android:layout_gravity="left|center"
        android:spacing="15dip" />


    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btnColorNextPager"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/right_e"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the `LinearLayout` height , now you set the height to 50dp,

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ll_brand_color_slider_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="CHANGE_THE_HEIGHT_HERE"  
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/ll_product_view"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">
```

Comment: thanku for your answer..but its not working..height of linear layout changed but it does not affect image height...